# Getting an error while build a jar file with ant

Tags: java, ant

I have a jar.build.xml file and I want to build this file using ant. If I run:

```
ant -f jar.build.xml
```

I get this error:

[image]

could you please tell me, what does it mean and how can I solve that?

Comment: It **tells** you what is wrong.

Comment: yes but where should I put the junit? what should I do with Junit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you have to provide a `JUNIT_HOME` environment variable. (The directory where the JUnit library is located).

In order to provide such, do:

1. Open Start -> Right click on `Computer`
2. Open `Advanced System Settings`
3. Go to `Advanced` in the popup window and click on `Environment variables`.
4. Provide new varible under System variable. Name it `JUNIT_HOME` and give it a value the path where JUnit is located on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

try adding, this will read the system environment variables and stores them in properties

```
<property environment="env"/>
```

then

```
<echo message="Junit Home = ${env.JUNIT_HOME}"/>
```

will give you JUnit_home if it is set in system environment variable